# How to draw a contour diagram in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/393125/19661) at Math.SE contains a neat contour diagram created using Mathematica:
[image]

What Mathematica functions I can use to draw diagrams like this?

Comment: `Line`, `Arrow` and `Circle` inside `Graphics`; also `Point` and `Text`.  I imagine the contour was done "by hand", so to speak, inserting appropriate coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick 5 minute reproduction of the diagram (I've left the labeling of individual points out):

[image]

```
With[{ε = 0.05, L = 1, thick = AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
    Graphics[{
        thick, 
        Circle[{0, 0}, ε, {π/2, 3 π/2}], 
        Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.99}}], 
        Arrow[{{0, -ε}, {L, -ε}, {L, -L}, {-L, -L}, {-L, L}, {L, L}, {L, ε}, {0, ε}}], 
        Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(n\)]\)", FontSize -> 15], {L/2, 0.1}]
    }, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> thick, Ticks -> False]
]
```

The key points to make life simple are:

- Use a single `Arrow` chain for the entire length.
- Use the appropriate definition of `Arrowheads` to specify the position of the arrow head.
- Use `AbsoluteThickness` to get a uniform thickness.
- Use the 3 argument form of `Circle` to draw arcs.

Answer (score 6):

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, Pi/2 {1, 3}], 
           Arrow[{{10, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
            Line[{{0, 1}, {10, 1}, {10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, -10}, {10, -10}, {10, -1}, {0, -1}}]},
         Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on 30K and 81K network, belisarius. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

One can use `Arrow` as following.

```
pts = {{0, -1}, {10, -1}, {10, -10}, {-10, -10}, {-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 1}};
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, Pi/2 {1, 3}], Arrowheads[{0, 0.03, 0}], 
  Arrow[{{10, 1}, {0, 1}}], Arrow[Partition[pts, 2, 1]]}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@1, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

And replace `Arrowheads[{0, 0.03, 0}]` to `Arrowheads[{0, 0.03, 0.03, 0}]` to get

[image]